# Share Your Practical Experience to build Android Application with Pre-Populated Database

Tags: android

Have you developed any android application which is using pre-populated database (say Size in between 1-5 MB , is size any issue?), If yes , May you please tell any trick which you used and work best for you ?

Or

If you developed any android application which gets data from file rather from database etc ? means initially you thought you might need to create the database and fill it up as pre-populated database but such techniques didn't work , so you applied some other techniques - e.g; you might used xyz file, and your application's business logic directly read the stuff from file and show on view - rather populating in database and then read from there ?

Please reply IF you have ever done that ? or something which is closed to solution

Answer (score 1):

Well i have created an application in which i had a database the dynamically changed often.

So what i found most common was to host some text documents on a server, and read the information i needed from the text file. And save it to the database and updated it every so often.

The only issue i ran into with this was that i had make sure the information in the text document was EXACTLY correct and how i needed it.

But this works absolutely great for my application i use it for.

But also you can consider using a HTML file, and parsing the information you need from it. Hosting it on a remote server and then parsing it as needed with a parser such as JSOUP or Apache Jericho.

JSOUP has worked well for me in the pass.

Answer (score 1):

I have an app that uses a prepopulated sqlite db. Yes, size is an issue: assets are limited to 1MB (I think this limit was removed on Android 2.3).

What I did is to split to db into chunks of 1MB and put them in the assets folder of my app, this way is ok with the limit and the assets get compressed. Then upon first launch of the app, I merge back these chunks and copy them into the external storage (or the internal if there is no external).

Comment: We have created an andriod application in which we are using preloaded databse.Our Sqlite database size is 227 KB but it in not getting port with the APK file. According to our understanding till now db file can not be port with the APK file. Please share your knowledge that how you have bind your db file in the asset folder.Please let us know that after putting your db file(which is less then 1 MB) in asset folder, Are you able to port it with APK. Thanks

Comment: You just need to copy your db file into your assets folder. At some point (after the app was installed in your device) you need to copy this file from the asset folder into the device storage.

Comment: The limitation is because of an issue in zipaligning the assets. Files above 1 MB are not compressed properly and hence cannot be copied properly until Android 2.2. But that has been fixed sice GB. 

I just changed the extension of the database to .mp3 file so that Android does not try to compress the asset for Android API <= 8; 

And for versions GB and above, I don't do this hack and so I get a compressed APK. I use this compressed APK, thus, leveraging the Android market's multi-APK support.